# Ember not able to configure routes correctly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

I have a problem with adding a simple route and am not sure how to debug it.

I have a route specified as follows

```
Videos.Router.map(function({
this.resource('videos', {path:'/');
this.route('forms');
})

Videos.FormsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
renderTemplate: function({
this.render({controller: 'forms'});
}
})
```

I also have a form template as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="forms">
```

But when I navigate to the url /forms  I get an error of page not found.

Any ideas where I could start looking to solve this?

Comment: Page not found makes me think the server you are using is trying to handle the request and can't figure out what to do (and subsequently not serving up a page, where the client does know what to do), what if you visit #/forms ?

Comment: Yes #forms works! thanks.  I'll have to do a bit more digging to understand what this means.  I'm using an Apache Server.

Answer (score 2):

To use non-hash urls like `/forms` you need to configure Ember's location to use html5 location.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

You will also need to configure your server to render the same index.html that is rendered when you visit `/forms`. This will vary as per your server.

For apache you'll need a `mod_rewrite` rule. For something like rails you need to add a catch all route to use your `HomeController`'s index page. Something like this at end of your routes.rb,

```
root :to 'home#index'
match "/*path" => 'home#index'
```

This tells the server that anything that doesn't match your previous routes should be rendered with `HomeController.index` method, or the specific controller that is rendering your application html.